# How to load data from ajax to zabuto calendar plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, calendar

As title, I tried load data from ajax to zabuto calendar, but seem it's not working, ref of zabuto calendar `http://zabuto.com/dev/calendar/examples/show_data.html`. And i want to use this function load data when click nav prev month or next month. (use two action `action` and `action_nav`). This is snipped code

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function () {
    function load_data() {
                    var list = '';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../BUS/WebService.asmx/LOAD_DATA",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            list = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                            console.log(list);
                        }
                    });
                    return list;
                }
       function myNavFunction(id) {
                //code in here
            }

            function myDateFunction(id) {
                //code in here
            }
    $("#my_calendar").zabuto_calendar({
                    data: load_data(),
                    action: function () {
                           return myDateFunction(this.id);
                    },
                    action_nav: function () {
                           return myNavFunction(this.id);
                    }
                });

    });

    </script>
```

When i test this, data not show, the data from ajax as 
`{ "date": "2016-06-01", "title": 2, "badge": true },{ "date": "2016-06-04", "title": 1, "badge": true },{ "date": "2016-06-10", "title": 1, "badge": true }`
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: you need to place the calendar function in the success function of the ajax call because ajax is asynchronous

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function load_data() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../BUS/WebService.asmx/LOAD_DATA",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var list = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                        $("#my_calendar").zabuto_calendar({
                           data: list;
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.d);
                    }
                });
            }


load_data();
});
```

Comment: Dear madalin ivascu, no other way, because I need to use more of both two zabuto action `action` and `action_nav`, change data when click nav prev month or next month,if that use this method can not be used that are two action.Thank you.

Comment: then use the build in ajax

Comment: Dear, i just update question,plz see it, and update some idea in your answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by the code as below. It works well in window's browser but not in a mobile browser.

```
function initZabuto(id, events, month){
    $('#zabuto_parent').empty().append("<div id='"+id+"'></div>");
    $("#"+id).zabuto_calendar({
        year:moment(month).format("YYYY"),
        month:moment(month).format("MM"),
        language:"cn",
        data: events,
        action: function () {
            zabutoDayClick(this.id);
        },
        action_nav: function () {
            zabutoMonthChange(this.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to refresh Zabuto calendar after a modal.  The problem with other options is that upon refresh, Zabuto would create a new batch of modals appended to the current body.  This solutions clears all those "old" modals and opens room for the new.  Key area is the success section of the modal update ajax.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date-popover").popover({html: true, trigger: "manual"});
    $("#date-popover").hide();
    $("#date-popover").click(function (e) {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    load_calendar();
});

function load_calendar() {
    $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
        show_next: 1,
        action: function () {
            return myDateFunction(this.id, false);
        },
        ajax: {
            url: "calendar-info.php",
            modal: true
        },
    });
}
        
function myDateFunction(id, fromModal) {
    $("#date-popover").hide();
    if (fromModal) {
        $("#" + id + "_modal").modal("hide");
        var date = $("#" + id).data("date");
        var optradio = $("#" + id + "_modal").find("input[name='optradio']:checked").val();
        $.ajax("calendar-update.php?status="+optradio+"&date="+date, {
            success: function(data) {
                $(".modal").remove();
                $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                $("#my-calendar").empty();
                load_calendar();
            },
            error: function() {
                  alert("Problem!");
            }
        });
    }
    var hasEvent = $("#" + id).data("hasEvent");
    if (hasEvent && !fromModal) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```